# Spring MVC Rest Client getting HttpClientErrorException: 404 null

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, http-status-code-404

I'm setting up a Rest Server along with client and i'm facing a problem for few hours already. When i call getPoints() method everything works fine, but when i call getPoint(Long id), deletePoint(Long id) and postPoint() i'm getting: Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 null.

Client Side:

```
public List<Point> getPoints()
{
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    ResponseEntity<List<Point>> pointResponse = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:5000/points", HttpMethod.GET, null,
            new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Point>>()
            {});
    List<Point> points = pointResponse.getBody();
    return (points);
}

public Point getPoint(long id)
{
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    Point point = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:5000/points" + id, Point.class);
    return point;
}

public void postPoint()
{
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:5000/points", this, this.getClass());
}

public void deletePoint(Long id)
{
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.delete("http://localhost:5000/points" + id);
}
```

Server Side:

```
public class PointsController {

private final PointsRepository repository;

PointsController(PointsRepository repository){
    this.repository=repository;
}

@GetMapping("/points/")
List<Points> all() {
    return repository.findAll();
}

@PostMapping("/points/")
Points newPoints(@RequestBody Points newPoints){
    return repository.save(newPoints);
}

@GetMapping(value = "/points/{id}/", produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
Resource<Points> one(@PathVariable Long id) {
    Points point = repository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new PointsNotFoundException(id));

    return new Resource<>(point,
            linkTo(methodOn(PointsController.class).one(id)).withSelfRel(),
            linkTo(methodOn(PointsController.class).all()).withRel("points"));
}

@DeleteMapping("/points/{id}/")
void deletePoints(@PathVariable Long id) {
    repository.deleteById(id);
}
```

}

What can cause the problem ? When i put on browser address: http://localhost:5000/points/1 i'm normally getting point with id 1.

Comment: I don't want to put this in an answer, but are you missing the trailing `/`

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't resolve the problem

Comment: You added the / on the server side instead of the client? See my answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string you are concenating in your `getPost()` method will be: `http://localhost:5000/points1` instead of `http://localhost:5000/points/1`.

Just add the `/`and you should be good to go

Comment: Thanks that helped with GetMapping and DeleteMapping, PostMapping still not working but it might be problem with my code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but can you try following:

```
public void postPoint()
{
  RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
  restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:5000/points/", this, this.getClass());
}
```

Because i saw the post mapping in the server side: `@PostMapping("/points/")`